# Responsive Filemanager preview images no theme icons

Tags: tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I am using latest 9.10.1 version of Response file manager http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/

But I have a problem with showing preview images. Instead of I have there icon theme. Only two images are visible as normal. Could you please gave me advice, what setting could I change to show all images (or if it's possible to show images < 2MB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in dialog.php on line 851

```
            if($img_width<122 && $img_height<91){
                $src_thumb=$current_path.$rfm_subfolder.$subdir.$file;
                $show_original=true;
            }
```

just comment if or increase width+height